# Which group takes CIP priority CH2OH or CH2OCH3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

I am confused why this structure is (2R, 3R) when CH2COMe takes priority over CH2OH which takes priority over CH3, surely it should be (2S, 2R)?

[image: Structure of the molecule]

Comment: Isn't it 3-ol? So what group has the highest priority?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you mistyped (2S,3R) as (2S,2R).

In fact (2R,3R) is correct because the "tie" between the top two groups is actually broken earlier than you suppose. When you get to the first carbon atom from C-2 the one in the group on the lower left is attached to $\ce{O,\color{blue}{H},H}$ and the one in the group on the lower right is attached to $\ce{O,\color{blue}{C},H}$. (What you think is $\ce{CH2OH}$ is actually $\ce{CH(C2H5)OH}$.) The difference between the blue atoms favors the right-hand group according to the CIP rules, and then the orientation at carbon atom 2 is rendered as R.